# Dynamic form builder database optimization Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, database-design, nosql

Hi I have a project that create forms dynamically I use a model like the following:

```
forms
-----
  id (PK)
  name
  (other fields)

form_fields
-------------
  id (PK)
  form_id (FK to forms.id)
  label (nome to the field)

form_submits (form inserted by someone user)
-------------
  id (PK)
  form_id (FK to forms.id)
  user_id (FK to users.id)

form_submits_fiels 
-------------
  id (PK)
  form_fields_id (FK to form_fields.id)
  form_submit_id (FK to form_submit.id)
  data
```

Now I have seriously problem whit the performance in the production server because the `form_element` table have more than 1.500.000 rows; the number continue growing and the function that return all records of a form take more that 20 seconds, the question is how optimizer the model or the query to take less time

I have some ideas but I thing that not resolve the problem:

- **Paginate:** if i could paginate the queries the performance will better so much but I thing that is not possible because the data was not in order.
- **MongoDB:** If use a no relational model the performance maybe will better but I not sure so mach can ber better with Mongo and is a so expensive solution

Comment: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Query_Questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I had more reputation, I would add a comment asking you to describe your indexes. As it is, I'll assume you don't have indexes since you didn't mention them.

First, consider using `EXPLAIN` on your queries to analyze the decisions the planner makes. 1.5m rows shouldn't take 20 seconds with any sort of reasonable combination of hardware and indexing. See the [documentation of the `EXPLAIN` modifier](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-explain.html) to get started with that. You should include `(ANALYZE on)` to see the cost breakdown and timing info from actually running the query, and more importantly the individual processes that go into each stage.

Second, a schema like this would benefit not only from indexes, but from some limited use of multi-column indexes. (See [`CREATE INDEX` documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createindex.html).) Consider creating indexes on:

- form_fields.formid, form_fields.id
- form_submits.formid, form_submits.id

and others. It depends highly on what your code is doing. Duplicate the database to another server and create different configurations of indexes and run your code against it. (`EXPLAIN (ANALYZE on)` again here!) Multi-column indexes are great because they help the planner check multiple filtering/sorting criteria in one pass of the index.

Third, to address your last points, I'm not sure that pagination or moving to a non-relational model will help. The fact that you're using foreign keys actually points to a strongly relational set of data. You can, of course, try MongoDB for free and see what the performance looks like.